# Summing up the scores in the Android Studio text view

Tags: java, android-studio, textview

How do I add the score in DisplayScore text view to the Totalpoint text view score?

I've tried and searched many times, but I haven't found an answer at all.

Somebody help me'

```
private String point;
private TextView DisplayScore;

point = getIntent().getExtras().get("point").toString();

DisplayScore = findViewById(R.id.displayScore);
DisplayScore.setText("point = " + point);
```

```
private void loadData() {

    reference.child(user.getUid())
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    ProfileModel model = snapshot.getValue(ProfileModel.class);
                    Totalpoint.setText(String.valueOf(model.getPoints()));


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(GameOverActivity.this, "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            });

}
```

private void updateDataFirebase() {

```
    int currentCoins = Integer.parseInt(Totalpoint.getText().toString());


    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("points", point);



    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
            .child(user.getUid())
            .updateChildren(map)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    }

                }
            });


}
```

Comment: I must admit I have no clue what is your problem. Three independent pieces of the code  (setting the TextView, some listener on value and finally update of Firebase DB) and at least I have no idea where is your problem. Sorry. You need to be much more precise in what you have tried and where is the problem.